# Polymer: Update dom-repeated elements when objects in an array are modified by outside code

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I'm using dom-repeat to list out a bunch of objects inside an array. The array is provided by outside code, so the modifications do not use Polymer's Array API.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w80xu0h/58/) showing what I have working. Is there a better (cleaner) way to handle this?

html

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">

<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="example-element">
    <template>
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color: cadetblue" on-tap="onTap">click me</div>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="item">
            <div>[[item.id]]</div>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<example-element></example-element>
```

js

```
//an array managed by code outside of this component.
var GLOBAL_ARRAY = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2}
];

Polymer({

  is: 'example-element',

  properties: {
    items:Array
  },

  ready: function() {
    this.items = GLOBAL_ARRAY;
  },

  onTap: function(evt) {
        //hold onto the old value before updating.
    var oldValue = GLOBAL_ARRAY[0];
    //just changing the property doesn't work regardless which notify is used below.
    //GLOBAL_ARRAY[0].id = Math.round(Math.random() * 50); 

    //replacing the entire object works with notifySplices() below.
    GLOBAL_ARRAY[0] = {id:Math.round(Math.random() * 50)};
        console.log('changed the first items id to ', GLOBAL_ARRAY[0].id);

    //doesn't work
    //this.notifyPath('items', GLOBAL_ARRAY);

    //works
    this.notifySplices('items', [{
      index:0,
        object:this.items,
      addedCount:1,
      removed:[oldValue],
      type:'splice'
    }]);
  }
});
```

I feel that using notifySplices() is wrong here since I'm not technically splicing at all. I would have expected notifyPath() to work, but it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to call notifyPath with the full path to the object property that was modified. The revised JS code is below.

```
//an array managed by code outside of this component.
var GLOBAL_ARRAY = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2}
];

Polymer({

  is: 'example-element',

  properties: {
    items:Array
  },

  ready: function() {
    this.items = GLOBAL_ARRAY;
  },

  onTap: function(evt) {
    GLOBAL_ARRAY[0].id = Math.round(Math.random() * 50); 
    this.notifyPath('items.0.id', GLOBAL_ARRAY[0].id);
  }
});
```

The [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3w80xu0h/64/).